# Why do you end up high on the Bristol stool scale when you are hungover?

Tags: digestion, alcohol, stomach, stools, hangover-hungover

Why do you end up high on the Bristol stool scale when you are hungover? What is it with alcohol that interrupts the normal processes in the bowel? Even if you drink plenty of alcohol, the amount of pure alcohol never exceeds 1-2 dl or so, which is quite minuscule compared to everything else you eat and drink every day.

Comment: I've never heard anyone report this effect. Maybe it's just you.

Comment: Pretty simple, really. I've never heard of it. There's no reason to insult people from Iran.

Comment: So why did you even comment if you didn't have knowledge about the issue at hand?

Comment: My comment is rather self-explanatory and benign. You really don't need to be so combative.

Comment: This needs to be clarified: what is "high up"? Which types of alcoholic drink? What else was consumed? In which time frame? etc. Beer, wine, whiskey, vodka: all are different in their effects. Currently this is much too broad and ill defined in most of the concepts to frame this question. Please [edit]!

Comment: High up = closer to 7 than to 1. Any alcoholic drink.

Comment: @hensti Do not reply in comments. Please [edit] the question so that it contains all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

The stool at the top of the image of [Bristol stool scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_stool_scale) looks as **separate hard lumps** (Type 1), which means there's a lack of water in it, which can be due to:

1. Drinking insufficient amount of water while drinking alcohol
2. Eating foods low in fiber (meat, dairy products, chips, white bread, cookies, chocolate, fast food...), which is common during drinking sessions

It's fiber, mainly [insoluble fiber](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/dietary-fiber-the-natural-solution-for-constipation#1), that absorbs water and makes the stool bulky ("normal"). Examples of foods high in insoluble fiber are whole grain bread, green leafy vegetables, legumes and fruits.

---

However, excessive alcohol drinking more likely results in **loose stools** (Type 6 or 7 in Bristol stool scale), which is a known [symptom of a hangover](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/7-steps-to-cure-your-hangover-and-ginkgo-biloba-whats-the-verdict).

It can be alcohol itself or something other in the drink that can irritate the bowel. Or it can be a mixture of drinks and foods that you are not used to or do not really go together...

Comment: Ah, but by "high on the Bristol stool scale" does OP mean at the top (a low number) or at the bottom (a high number)?

Comment: Well, waiting for a comment...In [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=bristol+stool+scale&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqx7-mgJDdAhWBKiwKHT3OBcIQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=925), constipation (Type 1) is usually on top.

Comment: A high number is usually higher up (i.e., on top) compared to a low number.

Comment: @hensti The content of your comment here might be needed edited into your question?